# What is more transparent, curl or wget in this web crawler project?

Tags: linux, proxy, php, wget, curl

I have files on a Windows 7, xampp server (using altered port, 181). I am triggering the script from another computer (linux) using `curl http://xxx.xxx.xxx:181/phpproject.php`

This PHP project is a web crawler using PHP cURL, that shuffles a list of proxies (http). I also have a script in the linux system that can fire `wget -O - http://xxx.xxx.xxx:181/phpproject.php` as another alternative. Is one more secure and are there ways for me to test for visibility.

The linux system happens to be BackTrack, so I have a good toolbox if any of that software could be of use for this project. I do have Task Scheduler dialed in on the Windows system, but wanted to try out remotely, leading to questions on what is more secure.

Comment: Which part of this chain are you asking about the security of? What do you mean by secure - secure from who/what? What threats are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @DuncanLock I am looking at never leaking my IP or cookies that can identify my primary IP to the scraped source. if one of the proxies allowed view of anything, I would like one system to be the net for this leak. That way I can set-up local IP's in accordance to not accidentally disrupt related services to the scraped source. Secondly, I just want to understand as a visual person, what I am looking for and how to "see" what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CURL & WGET are the same, from a transparency point of view - they're both plain text and anyone sniffing packets on the network can see what they're doing. Running them over [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) will create an encrypted tunnel and fix this.

To see what's going on inside your network *visually*, you need a copy of [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - a free, open source network protocol analyzer and packet inspector. If you run this on  either end, it will show you everything that that machine is sending/receiving over the network. It's just a desktop application and runs on both Windows and Linux. If you run it as Admin and have a capable network card, it can be run in 'Promiscuous Mode' which allows you to see everything happening on a local network from one machine.

If you're touching the public internet with this project - which it sounds like you are - then you will need something that creates encrypted tunnels (like SSH does for servers you control/login to) - but for the public internet in general. You also want something that will mask/change your public IP address. This thing is called a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) - there are numerous VPN providers that you can sign up for, such as [OverPlay](https://www.overplay.net/), who will provide you with VPN service for a fee.

Also, remember: always use your powers for good, not evil ;)

Comment: Great answer thank you. No evil here, but I do like to bypass quotas, max limitations and such.